# Unity C# Can't initialise list in void Start: getting error CS0103

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I am fresh to C# (I do program in other languages) and I got a task to record the position and rotation of an object inside Unity3D game.

I successfully created code that prints in Unity console current position and rotation with set timing (parts of `void RecPoint` without `lista`), and that at the end it saves all of the position data in one file (`void SaveToFile`).

What I wanted to do is to create one file for saving both position and rotation at the same time that looks like:

```
xposition; yposition; zposition; wrotation; xrotation; yrotation; zrotation
```

```
xposition; yposition; zposition; wrotation; xrotation; yrotation; zrotation
```

I wanted to achieve this by creating empty string list at the void Start and then adding position and rotation one step at the time (in void RecPoint). After that I would modify `void SaveToFile` to save everything similar to what is currently in `void SaveToFile`.

The problem is that no matter if I use `var lista = new List<string>()` or `lista = new List<string>()`.

I get the same error `CS0103` with the only difference being that when used var lista I don't get the `CS0103` error for this line.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ReadData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string fileName = "D:/position.txt";
    public List<Vector3> positions;
    public List<Quaternion> rotations;

    public float interval = 0.2f;
    public float tSample = 1.0f;

    void Start() 
    {
        positions = new List<Vector3>();
        rotations = new List<Quaternion>();
        var lista = new List<string>();
        InvokeRepeating("RecPoint", tSample, interval);
    }

    void RecPoint()
    {
        positions.Add(transform.position);
        rotations.Add(transform.rotation);
        lista.Add(transform.position.ToString());
        lista.Add(transform.rotation.ToString());
        Debug.Log("position " + transform.position + " rotation " + transform.rotation);
    }

    void SaveToFile(string fileName)
    {
        foreach (Vector3 pos in positions)
        {
            string line = System.String.Format("{0,3:f2};{1,3:f2};{2,3:f2}\r\n", pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fileName, line);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
        {
            CancelInvoke("RecPoint");
            SaveToFile(fileName);
            Debug.Log("Koniec czytania danych, zapisuję do pliku");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the *exact* compiler error you get, rather than just the identifier for it. I'm not surprised you see CS0103 in `RecPoint`, mind you - you haven't declared the field anywhere.

Comment: You’ve created lista in the start function which means that you can only use it within that start function. If you want it accessible elsewhere, make it an instance of the class similarly to how you’ve done it with rotations

Comment: @JonSkeet Error was about "lista" name, but apm11 solved this one for me.

Comment: @Beerman: "about lista name" still isn't the complete error message. In future, when you ask a question about an error, please copy/paste the *exact* error into your question. It makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is that you did not define the List "lista" anywhere.

Declare like so : `public List<string> lista;`
And then in Start() do : `lista = new List<string>();`

You can compress all of this into one line when declaring, like so : `public List<string> lista = new List<string>();`

Hope it helped!